# Redux: redux thunk never being called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using redux-thunks and am having an issue when calling an action. My code looks like this:

My action looks like this:

```
export const listTeams = (league: string) => {
    console.log('This is logged');  <------ This is logged

    return async dispatch => {

      console.log('never logged!!!!');   <------- never gets here

      await teamActions.listTeams(league)
            .then(team => {
               dispatch(setTeam(team));
            })
           .catch(error => handleErrors(error, dispatch));
      };
  };
```

and the component that calls it looks like this:

```
const App = () => {
   .... code

   const fetchData = async() => {
     await listTeams('Liverpool');
   };

   ... more code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that returns another function. So..

```
await listTeams('Liverpool')();
```

Comment: Thanks. That works but seems strange. Am I writing these actions wrong then? Is this normal? and also, now I see an error regarding the `dispatch` in the catch block

Comment: ah it's cos I was using it with `useDispatch` so it needed to be `dispatch(await listTeams('Liverpool'));`